# Unknown source error of GCM register

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make an Android app with notifications from server using new GCM, but I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
     at xx.xxxx.xxxx..MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:203)
     at xx.xxxx.xxxx..MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:195)
```

I made all necessary packages reference from "https://github.com/mosesmwongela/GCMDemo" and below is my code of main activity where I got the error:

```js
package xx.xxxx.xxxx;
import xx.xxxx.xxxx.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import xx.xxxx.xxxx.helper.SessionManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import static xx.xxxx.xxxx.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Asyntask
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    public static String name;
    public static String email;

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    Context context;
    String regId;

    public static final String REG_ID = "regId";
    private static final String APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";

    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

// Getting name, email from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();
        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        email = i.getStringExtra("email");

        // Get GCM registration id
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
            regId = registerGCM();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "GCM RegId: " + regId);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Registered with GCM Server!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Check if regid is present
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Registration is not present, register now with GCM
            regId = registerGCM();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "GCM RegId: " + regId);
        } else {
            // Device is already registered on GCM
            // Skips registration.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            final Context context = this;
        }

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);

        // Logout button click event
    }

    public String registerGCM() {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regId = getRegistrationId(context);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
            registerInBackground();
            Log.d("MainActivity",
                    "registerGCM - successfully registered with GCM server - regId: "
                            + regId);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "RegId already available. RegId: " + regId,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return regId;
    }

    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("RegisterActivity",
                    "I never expected this! Going down, going down!" + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: "
                            + regId);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;


                    storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error: " + msg);
                }
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Registered with GCM Server." + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();


                //Register user data on our server
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        ServerUtilities.register(getApplicationContext(), name, email, regId);
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }
                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences( MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void btnTips(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LatestTips.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     * */
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Ideas on where the problem should be?

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(registrationId==null)` in place of `if(registrationId.isEmpty())`

```
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId==null) // Change
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
```

Comment: GoogleCloudMessaging register and unregister methods are deprecated. I guess you should use InstanceID.getToken().